# How to install vNext build agent on CentOS (Linux)?

Tags: linux, azure, tfsbuild, azure-devops

Ive been trying to use Visual Studio Online's new build definitions with linux. I set up an Azure VM running CentOS 7.1 installed Nodejs (v0.10.36) and npm (v3.3.9) the prerequisites for the vNext build agent.

when running the vsoagent.js file to set up the agent and filling in the fields, i am able to connect to my VSO account successfully but the build agent doesnt start.

following is the console output i get:

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrUIN.png)

Im getting a bad request (400) error, why is this occuring and how do i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set some permissions before you can add and run a new agent. First, you need to enable alternate credentials for your account. Log in to VSO using your account and open your profile settings.

Then, go to the “Credentials” tab and enable your alternate credentials there.

After that, go back to the “Agent pools” administration page, go to Roles tab, there are two security groups there. You’ll need to add your account to both.

•Agent Pool Administrators:  allows adding agent to pool

•Agent Pool Service Accounts: allows the agent to listen to the build queue

When you create the server, you'll need to login using the credentials you provided when creating the virtual machine. More steps of creating a Build.vNext agent on Linux, please check http://realalm.com/2015/06/26/creating-a-build-vnext-agent-on-linux/

Comment: there should be nothing to do with the account permission. From the screenshot Karl provided, you will see that Karl actually is successfully connected.

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot you provided, you got bad request with the URL.
[image]

And the server URL you need to provide should be something like: https://servername.visualstudio.com